# JavaScript: how can I use async/await to "await" something that happens in MutationObserver?

Tags: async-await, mutation-observers

I have a `forEach` loop that processes data in an array. Somewhere in the middle of that loop I have to wait for a change in a DOM element, grab that change, process it, and only then can I continue processing the array.

I'm hoping to see this in console:

```
Preparing "aaa"
Waiting for result on "aaa"
Processing result on "aaa": <random number>
Got result for "aaa": <random number>something`
```

And the same thing for each element in `stuffToProcess` array in the code snippet below. It's a simplified example of the code.

I realize similar questions have been asked and answered countless times before, but after reading through many of them, and trying many different things for hours, I still can't figure this one out.

```js
function dummy() {
  $('#trackMe').text(Math.random());
}

async function doWork(stuffToProcess) {
  let target = $('#trackMe')[0];
  let config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, values: true };
  
  let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations,item) {
    console.log('Processing result on "%s": %s', item, target.innerText);
    item = item + 'something';
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      resolve(item);
    });
  });

  observer.observe(target, config);

  stuffToProcess.forEach(async function(item) {
    console.log('Preparing "%s"', item);
    console.log('Waiting for result on "%s"', item);
    let change = await observer(item);
    //^^^ this needs to "await" for data from observer before the loop continues
    console.log('Got result for "%s": %s', item, change);
  });

  //observer.disconnect();

}

doWork(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="trackMe">No changes yet</p>
<button onclick="dummy()">Click me to change</button>
```

Comment: The promise constructor should be created outside the observer constructor, resolve should be inside.

Comment: But how can I then make the forEach loop await data from the observer, if the observer can't "push" that data back? Is it feasible to wrap the whole observer in an async function, then call that function in the forEach loop? I tried that too before, but the code just kept running and I got the returns from the observer at the very end... I'm usually more on the sysadmin side, less programming, so I'm probably doing something very wrong here... :)

Comment: ES7 async generator function might help I guess.

Comment: Hey @wOxxOm, I managed to find a way to make this work. If you have some comments regarding the solution, I'll gladly read them.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I managed to solve it somehow. Probably not the cleanest solution though, so if anyone recommends any improvements on this, I'll happily edit the solution / upvote your answer.

```js
function dummy() {
  $('#trackMe').text(Math.random());
}

async function doWork(stuffToProcess) {
  let target = $('#trackMe')[0];
  let config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    values: true
  };

  let observer;

  function isItDone(item) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {

      observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        console.log('Processing result on "%s": %s', item, target.innerText);
        result = target.innerText + 'something';
        resolve(result);
      });

      observer.observe(target, config);
    });
  }


  for (index in stuffToProcess) {
    console.log('Preparing "%s"', stuffToProcess[index]);
    console.log('Waiting for result on "%s"', stuffToProcess[index]);

    let change = await isItDone(stuffToProcess[index]);
    observer.disconnect();

    console.log('Got result for "%s": %s', stuffToProcess[index], change);
  }
}

doWork(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="trackMe">No changes yet</p>
<button onclick="dummy()">Click me to change</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example using only JavaScript, I hope it helps you.

```js
function getData() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // resolve();
        // reject();
    });
}

function example1() {
    // code ...

    async function getAsyncData() {
        let data = await getData();
        console.log(data);
        // code ...
    }

    let element = document.getElementById(...);
    let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        getAsyncData();
    });
    let config = {attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true};
    observer.observe(element, config);

    // code ...
}
```